# Cómo corregir "valueError: Invalid field" en Odoo

Tags: python, postgresql, mvc, odoo

En el módulo de inventario de odoo estoy haciendo unas modificaciones en la parte de recepciones, que es el modelo *stock_picking*. La finalidad de esto es que desde el módulo de contactos haga un filtrado de etiquetas y que solo muestre los nombres de las personas que tienen la etiqueta proveedor, pero a la hora de desplegar el campo manda que la instrucción para hacer eso es inválida.

Este es mi código:

```
    partner_id = fields.Many2one(
    'res.partner', 'Contact',
    domain=[('tag_ids.name', '=', 'proveedor')],
    check_company=True,
    states={'done': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]})
```

Donde estoy haciendo el proceso de filtrado es en domain pero en la interfaz a la hora de hacer el filtrado manda el siguiente error:

[image: valueError Invalid field]

El error dice que esa instrucción de domain no es válida. ¿Qué podría hacer para corregir este error y que haga el filtrado de forma correcta?

Comment: Puedes copiar el error como texto?

Comment: ya no tengo el error puse mal el campo ahora el problema que tengo es que no me manda los nomres que correspondan a ese tag solo lo manda vacio y dice que empiece a escribir

Comment: No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pon siempre el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_.